# Change Light Colour of a Custom Block

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-resource-packs, minecraft-addons

I recently created a resource+behaviour pack for Minecraft Bedrock Edition, with custom light source blocks, named `number_zero`, `number_one`, And so on until `number_nine`.

Unfortunately, these light sources only have a white glow.
How do you change a custom light source’s colour?

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is *off-topic* due to the fact that light emission is controlled in the behavior pack. However, I will say that it's not currently possible to change the color of emitted light. The only things that have colored light in BE are the new torches in education edition which aren't available through the vanilla packs for us to manipulate.

Comment: @Tacoタコス Ok. Thank you!